# Listen to multiple actions in redux-observable

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-observable

Can I listen to multiple actions, instead of just one?

Right now, to achieve that, I'm doing it in multiple epics, using `combineEpics` helper:

```
combineEpics(
  action$ => action$.ofType("SOME_TYPE_A").mapTo(newAction),
  action$ => action$.ofType("SOME_TYPE_B").mapTo(newAction)
);
```

However, I can use `filter` instead:

```
action$ =>
  action$
    .filter(({ type }) => type === "SOME_TYPE_A" || type === "SOME_TYPE_B")
    .mapTo(newAction);
```

But it's not scalable, when I need to listen for 5 actions, for example.

Is there exists more elegant way to listen multiple actions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ofType`](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/blob/master/src/ActionsObservable.js#L26) can take multiple keys, so you could use:

```
action$ => action$.ofType("SOME_TYPE_A", "SOME_TYPE_B").mapTo(newAction),
```

Comment: so does it mean that match will happen if either action is of type SOME_TYPE_A OR SOME_TYPE_B ?

Comment: yes it would be a stream of any action that matches either of those